# BeautifulSoup, save scrape results in text file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from a table with BeautifulSoup and save this to a file. I wrote this:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://dofollow.netsons.org/table1.htm"

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    print "%s, %s, %s" % (tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text)
```

which works.

I then tried to write the results to a file but it is not working. :(

```
logfile = open("log.txt", 'a')             
logfile.write("%s,%s,%s\n" % (tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text))   
logfile.close()
```

How can save my results in a test file?

Comment: How is it not working? What did you expect to see? Is `log.txt` there, but empty? Did you get an error message? If so, please post the full traceback.

Comment: yes, the file is empty !

Comment: I think you got a `UnicodeEncodeError` error, why didn't you include that in your queston?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/g1RSE2Qk

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to add information like that.

Comment: And do not use a bare `except:` handler, that *masks* the error you got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BeautifulSoup gives you Unicode data, which you need to encode before writing it to a file.

It'll be easier if you use the `io` library, which lets you open a file object with transparent encoding:

```
import io

with io.open('log.txt', 'a', encoding='utf8') as logfile:
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        logfile.write(u"%s, %s, %s\n" % (tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text))
```

The `with` statement takes care of closing the file object for you.

I used UTF8 as the codec, but you can pick any that can handle all codepoints used in the pages you are scraping.