# Python: Regex v. BeautifulSoup to remove from text <TYPE>

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I need to remove all sections from a text between tags `<TYPE>EX` and `</TEXT>` and `<TYPE>XML` and `</TEXT>`. I was thinking to use regex as follow:

```
re.sub(r"(?is)<TYPE>EX[^>]*>(.*?)</TEXT>",'',text)
```

and

```
re.sub(r"(?is)<TYPE>XML[^>]*>(.*?)</TEXT>",'',text)
```

But I keep on reading on StackOverflow not to use `regex` if `BeautifulSoup` can do the job. How can I use BeautifulSoup to remove content between these tags in my text? I don't think this is correct:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text.lower())
[s.extract() for s in soup('TYPE')]
```

I have to specify `<TYPE>EX` and `<TYPE>XML`. The closing tag is really `</TEXT>` in both cases. A sample .txt file can be found [here](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312513416534/0001193125-13-416534.txt). Should simply stick to regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression (yes) to match the contained text:

```
soup.find_all('TYPE', text=re.compile('^\s*(?:EX|XML)', re.I))
```

This will find all tags with tagname `TYPE`, whose directly contained text starts with `EX` or `XML` (case insensitively) but allowing for whitespace between the opening tag and the text.

You can then extract those tags to remove them:

```
for type_tag in soup.find_all('TYPE', text=re.compile('^\s*(?:EX|XML)', re.I)):
    type_tag.extract()
```

I am assuming you parsed the document as *XML*, with `BeautifulSoup(text, 'xml')`; otherwise tags are matched case-insensitively and you need to *lowercase* the tags you are looking for (e.g. `find_all('type', ....)`). You'll need to have [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) installed for BeautifulSoup to support XML parsing.

Comment: I am trying this out and I get this error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` for `for type_tag in soup.find_all('type', text=re.compile('^\s*(?:ex|xml)', re.I)):
    type_tag.extract()`
I put everything in lower case as follow: `soup = BeautifulSoup(text.read().lower())` where `text = open("C:\\Users\\0001193125-13-416534.txt")`. Why do I get this error? Thanks for the help

Comment: @Plug4: that sounds like you are using BeautifulSoup version *three* rather than four. Make sure you have the right version; for the latter you'd use `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: I see that was my issue. Since I am new to BeautifulSoup, how can I export my `soup` text to a .txt file? I tried `text_file = open("C:\\Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(soup)
text_file.close()` but it gives me this error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`

Comment: If I try your suggestion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968279/beautifulsoup-save-scrape-results-in-text-file I get an empty `.txt` file ...

Comment: @Plug4: can you create a new question for that issue?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048178/python-saving-beautifulsoup-output-to-text-file thanks for the suggestion