# Python: Saving BeautifulSoup Output to Text file

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

This question is a follow-up to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035993/python-regex-v-beautifulsoup-to-remove-from-text-type/27036090?noredirect=1#comment42612843_27036090).

I am parsing a txt file in Python as follow:

```
text = open("C:\\Users\\0001193125-13-416534.txt")
soup = BeautifulSoup(text.read().lower())
for type_tag in soup.find_all('TYPE', text=re.compile('^\s*(?:EX|XML)', re.I)):
    type_tag.extract()
```

Once I have extracted all the `<TYPE>` tags from `soup`, how can I save the ouptut to a txt file? I have tried:

```
with io.open("C:\\Output.txt", 'a', encoding='utf8') as logfile:
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        logfile.write(u"%s, %s, %s\n" % (tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text))
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968279/beautifulsoup-save-scrape-results-in-text-file) but no success. I end up with an empty `output.txt` file.

Comment: And you've done a quick `print` debug to make sure that you see the result you're expecting right?

Comment: yes if I do `print soup` after the parsing I see my desired output

Comment: I'm referring to the part immediately before you go to `logfile.write`, so what do you see if you `print(tds)` before writing to the file?

Comment: ah I see nothing .... but wait... I should simply do the the following: `text = str(soup)` and then `text_file = open("C:\\Output.txt", 'w')
text_file.write(x)
text_file.close()` ... that seems to work. Is this a correct way to do things?

Comment: Sure you can do that but when you do `text_file.write(x)` the `x` should be a `list` of whatever you wanted to initially get from the `soup` (as opposed to the entire `soup`)

Comment: Note, you do *not* need to lowercase your input; BeautifulSoup by default parses your document as HTML and will treat all tags as case-insensitive anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes your right! I think I should close my question because turning `soup` in strip does the job.